# Problema al proteger al definir una requiresAuth en VueRouter firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Estoy haciendo una pequeña practica con `Vue` y `Firebase`, ya he logrado crear usuarios y configurar bien `Firebase` pero tengo un problema a la hora de restringir rutas con `VueRouter`, con lo que he leído debería bastar con la propiedad `requiresAuth` para restringirla si no hay usuario logueado, pero no funciona de esta forma:

```
{
  path: '/home',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home,
  meta: { requiresAuth: true }
}
```

Pero la ruta sigue siendo accesible a pesar de que no haya iniciado sesión ningún usuario. ¿Hace falta alguna configuración extra?

Mi archivo de rutas es este:

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
routes: [
{
  path: '*',
  redirect: '/'
},
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Index',
  component: Index
},
{
  path: '/register',
  name: 'Register',
  component: Register
},
{
  path: '/home',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Home,
  meta: { requiresAuth: true }
}
]
})

Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
let usuarioActivo = firebase.auth().currentUser;
let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

if (requiresAuth && !usuarioActivo) next('index')
else if (!requiresAuth && usuarioActivo) next('home')
else next()
})
```

Al agregar el beforeEach y preguntar si la ruta requiere autorizacion me tira este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y mostrarnos el contenido del archivo donde has definido las rutas? Te recomiendo leer [este articulo](https://medium.com/@anas.mammeri/vue-2-firebase-how-to-build-a-vue-app-with-firebase-authentication-system-in-15-minutes-fdce6f289c3c)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Marcos, he editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El error lo recibes porque estas llamando al método `beforeEach` sobre el componente `Router`, cuando deberías hacerlo sobre instancia devuelta por `new Router()`.

### Solución:

- Debes crear una instancia de router. Así por ejemplo, `let router = new Router(...)`
- Sobre variable `router` es que debes llamar al método [`beforeEach`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

#### Ejemplo:

```
Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  routes: [{
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/'
  }, {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Index',
    component: Index
  }, {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Register',
    component: Register
  }, {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let usuarioActivo = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if (requiresAuth && !usuarioActivo) next('index')
  else if (!requiresAuth && usuarioActivo) next('home')
  else next()
})

export default router
```

Comment: Muchas gracias marcos, con tus correcciones ya no me tira el error, pero sigue sin bloquearme la entrada la ruta '/home', si la escribo en el navegador puedo seguir accediendo a ella.

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante claro. No existe la función `beforeEach` en `Router`. Debes acceder al método desde el objeto creado con [**`new Router()`**](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Puedes hacer:

```
const router = new Router(...)
router.beforeEach(...)
export default router
```

Nada te impide hacer esto:

```
const router = new Router(...)
export default router
router.beforeEach(...)
```

O también puedes hacer (La mejor opción en mi opinión):

```
export default router = new Router(...)
router.beforeEach(...)
```

[**`Referencia de interés`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/export)

Comment: Muchas, con tus correcciones ya no me tira el error, pero sigue sin bloquearme la entrada la ruta '/home', si la escribo en el navegador puedo seguir accediendo a ella.